# handling methods which accept hash values in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with the following method:

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :value
  def value
    @value = {}
  end
end
```

In my form, I have the following:

```
f.text_field "value[start_range]"
```

When form is submitted I would like the params hash to look as follows:

```
{leads => { :value => { "start_range" => "some value", "arbitrary_data" => "something else" } } }
```

In other words, name/value pairs from inputs get inserted as key/value pairs in the value method.

However, instead I get the following error:

```
undefined method `value[start_range]' for #<Lead:0x007ff83321a4c0>
```

Clearly, it is looking for a method called value[start_range], when I have method called value which is a hash that can have any key it wants, including start_range.

How can I address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that 'serialize' method is fit for your needs.

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :value
  serialize :value, Hash
end
```

and for the view

```
text_field_tag 'value[start_range]'
```

Comment: It is still giving me undefined method `value[start_range]' when I try to load the new form.

Comment: on the view, please try to use the text_field_tag method